# Merge rows based on date range

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df with hundreds of columns and thousands of rows.
Here are the 3 columns that interest us:

| ID | startDate | endDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-25 |
| 123 | 2020-01-26 | 2020-02-08 |
| 123 | 2020-02-09 | 2020-03-12 |

I want for each row with the same ID, merge the rows if the dates follow each others, and keep all other columns intact.

For our example, the output would be a single row because the dates follow:

| ID | startDate | endDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-03-12 |

Do you have an idea on how to do it with pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If datetimes are not sorted or not sure use `min` and `max` for aggregation:

```
df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).agg({'startDate': 'min', 'endDate': 'max'})
```

If there is a lot another columns and need aggregate only 2 columns:

```
df['startDate'] = df.groupby('ID')['startDate'].transform('min')
df['endDate'] = df.groupby('ID')['endDate'].transform('max')

df = df.drop_duplicates('ID')
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! But it only gives me these 3 columns. How do I aggregate and keep all other columns of the df? Do I have to type them all in the `agg` ?

Comment: @Awans - Another columns need aggregate by `sum` or something else?

Comment: No, other columns don't need to be modified, they are the same for all these rows, but I need to keep them

Comment: @Awans - Added to answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try `groupby` with `agg` and `first` with `last`:

```
>>> df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).agg({'startDate': 'first', 'endDate': 'last'})
    ID   startDate     endDate
0  123  2020-01-01  2020-03-12
>>>
```